# Array of type that user enter

Tags: c, arrays, ncurses

I write:

```
printw("\nNow, Which is the type of data to be saved?\n");
printw("\n1- Integer\n2- Short-integer\n3- Char\n4- Float\n");
printw("\nSelect the number of the option (1-4)\n");

do{
    scanf("%d",&h);
    switch(h){
        case 1:
            int matriz[rows][columns];
            break;
        case 2:
            short int matriz[rows][columns];
            break;
        case 3:
            char matriz[rows][columns];
            break;
        case 4:
            float matriz[rows][columns];
            break;
        default:
            printw("\nYou have to enter a number between 1 and 4 :)\n");
            break;


    }
}while(h > 4 || h < 1);
```

(Previously I defined h, rows, colunmns and I am using ncurses)

I want to do an array of the type that user wants. But I realized that this isn't the way.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly ?

Comment: Wrap each `case` with `{` and `}` and use the arrays from each `case`.

Comment: I want to make this program to practice, only with that aim :) @MichaelWalz

Comment: I think what you're trying to do is declare `matriz` with a different type depending on user input and then (presumably) use `matriz` to actually do something later.  There ways to get something sort of like this in C but it will be far more complicated than what you're probable looking for.

Comment: also, I'd recommend you use `printf` or `puts` instead of using `printw` (from ncurses?)

Answer (score -1):

Typical case of type generic programming in C. It can be done but it is a bit burdensome:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROWS 2
#define COLS 3


typedef enum
{
  TYPE_INT,
  TYPE_SHORT,
  TYPE_CHAR,
  TYPE_FLOAT
} type_t;


typedef struct generic_t generic_t; // forward declaration, incomplete type

// generic print function type
typedef void(*print_func_t ) (const generic_t* ptr, size_t row, size_t col);

typedef struct generic_t
{
  type_t        type;   // corresponding to selected data type
  print_func_t  print_func;
  void*         matrix2D;
} generic_t;


// specific print function just for float
void print_float (const generic_t* ptr, size_t row, size_t col);


int main()
{
  generic_t data;

  // take user input etc, determine type selected

  // lets assume they picked float
  data.type = TYPE_FLOAT;
  data.print_func = print_float;
  data.matrix2D = malloc (ROWS*COLS*sizeof(float));

  float some_data[2][3] =   // some random data:
  {
    {1, 2, 3}, 
    {4, 5, 6}, 
  };
  memcpy(data.matrix2D, some_data, ROWS*COLS*sizeof(float));

  for(size_t r=0; r<ROWS; r++)
  {
    for(size_t c=0; c<COLS; c++)
    {
      data.print_func(&data, r, c);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  free(data.matrix2D);
}


void print_float (const generic_t* ptr, size_t row, size_t col)
{
  float(*fmatrix)[COLS] = ptr->matrix2D; // cast to a pointer to a 2D float array
  printf("%f ", fmatrix[row][col]); // treat data as 2D array of float
}
```

You can create similar functions depending on what you want to do with the data, one function for each possible type.

Answer (score -1):

As said in the comments, if you only wish to use `matriz` in each `case` independently from the others, you just have to put each `case`'s body inside its own block with `{` ... `}`. If on the contrary you want to access `matriz` in the whole body of your function, you have to declare it before the `switch`, and with a type that encompasses all possible uses. This is what `union`s are for.

In the following example, `enum kind` is used to recall the choice of the user, while `union container` can store any of your four choices. Then, in the `main` function, based on the value of `k`, you can decide which type of value must be in the cells of `matriz`, and use the appropriate field of `union container` to access them.

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int rows = 3;
const int columns = 3;

enum kind { INT, SHORT, CHAR, FLOAT };
union container { int ival; short sval; char cval; float fval; };

int main() {
enum kind k;
union container matriz[rows][columns];
int h;
do{
    scanf("%d",&h);
    switch(h){
      case 1:
          k = INT;
          break;
      case 2:
          k = SHORT;
          break;
      case 3:
          k = CHAR;
          break;
      case 4:
          k = FLOAT;
          break;
      default:
        printf("\nYou have to enter a number between 1 and 4 :)\n");
        break;
    }
 } while(h > 4 || h < 1);

 if (k == FLOAT) matriz[0][0].fval = 0.0;
 if (k == INT) matriz[0][0].ival = -1;
 if (k == SHORT) matriz[0][0].sval = 2;
 if (k == CHAR) matriz[0][0].cval = 'a';

 return 0;
}
```